# .Net Core Web API Get function not returning data

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core GET function that used to work but, for whatever reason, is no longer returning data. I've tested it in Fiddler. I swore that I hadn't changed anything in the function itself since I last tested it. The only thing I've done that may have affected it is to upgrade the project from .Net Core 2.1 to .Net Core 3.1.

The GET Function:

```csharp
[HttpGet]
[Produces(typeof(FrameImageDTO))]
public IQueryable GetAll()
{
    var results = from f in _context.Frames
    where f.Child.ParentId == LoggedInUser.ParentId
    select new FrameImageDTO(f);

    Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Total-Count", _frameRepository.GetAll().Count().ToString());

    return results;
}
```

The DTO:

```csharp
public class FrameImageDTO
{
    public byte[] ImageData;

    public float XPosition;
    public float YPosition;
    public float ZPosition;
    public float XRotation;
    public float YRotation;
    public float ZRotation;
    public string FrameName;
    public long ChildId;

    public FrameImageDTO(Frames frame)
    {
        if (frame == null) return;

        XPosition = frame.XPosition;
        YPosition = frame.YPosition;
        ZPosition = frame.ZPosition;
        XRotation = frame.XRotation;
        YRotation = frame.YRotation;
        ZRotation = frame.ZRotation;
        FrameName = frame.FrameName;
        ChildId = frame.ChildId;

        // Retrieve file
        string filename = frame.Filename;

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "User Image Store", filename), FileMode.Open);
        var bytesToRead = (int)fileStream.Length;

        ImageData = new byte[bytesToRead];
        fileStream.Read(ImageData, 0, bytesToRead);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint to examine the content of 'results' in the GET function, it's populated with data but when I test it in Fiddler, there's no data.

EDIT:

I've remembered that something I had changed was the Startup. I have another Web API project which has a cleaner looking startup class than this one does so I used that as the basis for cleaning up this one. Is there anything in here that looks out of place or is missing? I've so far tried everything and the only thing it seems to want to return is an ObjectResult.

```csharp
 public class Startup
 {
     public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
     {
         Configuration = configuration;
     }

     public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

     // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         services.AddScoped<ICountryRepository, CountryRepository>();
         services.AddScoped<IParentRepository, ParentRepository>();
         services.AddScoped<IChildRepository, ChildRepository>();
         services.AddScoped<IDiaryEntryRepository, DiaryEntryRepository>();
         services.AddScoped<IDiaryRepository, DiaryRepository>();
         services.AddScoped<IImageRepository, ImageRepository>();
         services.AddScoped<IFrameRepository, FrameRepository>();

         services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
         {
             // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
             options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
             options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
         });

         services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Blah Blah"), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

         services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

         services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
         services.AddControllers();
         services.AddRazorPages();

         services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
         services.AddControllers();

         services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
         {
             options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
             options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
             options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
         });

         services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
         services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

         services.AddTransient<IPrincipal>(provider => provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);
     }

     // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
     {
         if (env.IsDevelopment())
         {
             app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
             app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
         }
         else
         {
             app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
             app.UseHsts();
         }

         app.UseAuthentication();

         app.UseHttpsRedirection();
         app.UseStaticFiles();
         app.UseCookiePolicy();

         app.UseRouting();

         app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
         {
             endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                 name: "default",
                 pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
             endpoints.MapRazorPages();
         });

         // For Unity WebGL integration
         app.UseFileServer();
         StaticFileOptions staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions()
         {
             FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                 Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Template")),
             RequestPath = new PathString("/template")
         };
         app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
         FileExtensionContentTypeProvider contentTypeProvider = (FileExtensionContentTypeProvider)staticFileOptions.ContentTypeProvider ??
             new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
         contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".unityweb", "application/octet-stream");
         staticFileOptions.ContentTypeProvider = contentTypeProvider;
         app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);

         // If Unity doesn't work, consider changing or deleting this line
         //app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
         //{
         //    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "User Image Store")),
         //    RequestPath = "/ImageStore"
         //});

         //CreateRoles(serviceProvider);
     }
```

Comment: What is `LoggedInUser.ParentId`?

Comment: Did you tried to change the `IQueryable` to `IActionResult` and `return results;` to `return Ok(results)`?

Comment: The @Cristian Szpisjak suggestion probably will fix your problem. you can not use IQueryable in a controller

Comment: The LoggedInUser.ParentId is a bit of a cludge. It's temporary storage to remove a round trip to the database (and to get around something that just wouldn't work any other way). Thanks, Christian, I'll try that. I did play around with it and changed it to IActionResult but wasn't sure how to return the results back when using that LINQ created object.

Comment: Ah! Dangit! Didn't fix it. I have other GET functions and they all work. They return an ObjectResult. The only reason this one doesn't is that I'm using LINQ to initialise the DTO. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do but return an ObjectResult?

Comment: You can have like `public List<FrameImageDTO> GetAll...` and use `return results.ToList()` instead. This decoration here `[Produces(typeof(FrameImageDTO))]` should also be representative to the data type you're returning so maybe try `[Produces(typeof(List<FrameImageDTO>))]`

Comment: Tried that and no luck. I've had a thought and have updated the original post accordingly.

Comment: If you try to return `from f in _frameRepository.GetAll() select f` and see if you are getting result; which will generate IQuaryable and help in debug?

Comment: The thing is, I am getting results from the query. The problem lies in getting the function to return those results via JSON. I can see in Fiddler that it's trying to return something. If it finds 8 records, Fiddler shows me that there are 8 records there but they're empty.

Comment: Fixed it. I was able to track the issue down to the DTO. Seems that it needed fully defined properties with getters and setters. The odd thing is that it was working and since fixing it, I've found articles that suggest it shouldn't have worked. Perhaps Microsoft tightened things up in 3.1?